# Can't hide object which particles are based on, without losing particles

Tags: particles

To clarify i'm not in this instance trying to hide emitter. The emitter oblong shape with arrow is supposed to be there. The particles are all based on a torus shape so all the little pink coins are based on that but i want to hide from render the large torus i have elsewhere on the screen. I un-clicked camera under ray visibility but then lost both the particles and the large torus. Thanks for any tips.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the large torus.

**Blender 2.7x**

Press the <kbd>M</kbd> key and change the layer it lives on.

[image: Move to layer]

Then in render layers Shift-Select the layer you chose to remove that layer from being render.

[image: enter link description here]

**Blender 2.8x**

Go to the *Object Properties panel*.

**De-select** *Show in renders*

[image: Object Properties panel]

To explain this, the properties you are changing ar only for the instance you selected, not any instances that are generated by the particle system.

Comment: @Gooniezmedia feel free to upvote all relevant answers and mark your accepted solution.

Comment: Moog: I would like to delete my answer, would you mind extend your "A" with some Outliner info to cover all options? So newcomers can get answer from one place, thank you.I would like to delete my answer, would you mind extend your "A" with some Outliner info to cover all options? So newcomers can get answer from one place, thank you.

Comment: Am I right that this stopped working in 3.0? In 3.0, when I deselect show in viewport/renders, not only the instance, but also the instances generated by the particle system are affected.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too trivial a solution, but could you just move the torus off-screen?

Keep in mind, if you change the world position of the torus, it will affect the particle's position too if Object -> Global Coordinates is checked under the "Particles" context

Answer (score 1):

You can hide Torus from Outliner Editor (Blender 2.8x).

[image]

[image]