# How to hide particle system original object?

Tags: rendering, particles, add-on, linked-data, instances

I am working on a very complex scene, including areas that have particle systems (grass, flowers, etc.), mostly created with the Botaniq and Graswald addons.

Because the scene is so heavy, I have broken it down in sections and I am linking each area into the main file, instead of appending.

The problem is, when these areas come into the main file, the particle systems' collections (instancing objects) are visible and on ground level, meaning they are are showing up on the render.

Is there any way to hide these things or what is usually the procedure?

Bonus question: For such a heavy file, is it better to work with linked files or just appending? Does anyone know what is more optimized?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160413/cant-hide-object-which-particles-are-based-on-without-losing-particles

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't hide object which particles are based on, without losing particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160413/cant-hide-object-which-particles-are-based-on-without-losing-particles)